# Deselect the text in a NSTextField

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

Is there an easy way to deselect an `NSTextField` *after* pressing enter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you will need to make your view controller the delegate of your text field. Then you override `NSControl` instance method `controlTextDidEndEditing(_:)`, get your textfield current editor selected range 
and from the main thread set it back to your textfield:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
    }
    override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        if let selectedRange = textField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.textField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange = selectedRange
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it does deselect the textfiled but what im looking for is it, deselecting the text and keeping the text selector wherever it was at

Comment: bassicly im looking for a way to prevent the textfiled from auto selecting all the text when enter is pressed

Comment: works, but this just reselect the text after its been deselected i was looking for a way to prevent the textfield from auto selecting alltogether, i dont know why it by defaut, has this behavior

Comment: can't tumb you up yet my repution isnt high enough

Comment: where do i click to aprouve ur answer?

Comment: i aprouved it now

Comment: @jana_lemmings I have made some questions at your other question

Comment: i think i nswered them

Comment: @jana_lemmings check my comment there

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way I did it.

By disabling it with `isSelectable` and `isEditable` and then setting a timer to re-enable it after 0.5s

```
@IBAction func timeCodeChanged(_: NSTextField) {
    timecodeLabel.isSelectable = false
    timecodeLabel.isEditable = false
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(reEnableLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func reEnableLabel() {
    timecodeLabel.isSelectable = true
    timecodeLabel.isEditable = true
}
```